# View Rows/Columns in DataTable Object in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a `DataTable` object that has rows/columns and I'd like to be able to see those rows/columns from inside VS 2012. Here is a screenshot of when I hover over the `DataTable`:

[image]

I've tried clicking through pretty much all of those nodes that can be expanded, but I still cannot determine where (through this little window) I can see the rows/columns of my `DataTable`.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the magnifying glass in your screenshot above to use the [DataTable Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d480bk47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).